# $x$ positive implies $\text{Tr}(x-)$ positive.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, trace

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $x \in T(H)$ be a positive trace class operator. I want to show that
$$\text{Tr}(x-): B(H) \to \mathbb{C}: y \mapsto \text{Tr}(xy)$$
is a positive functional.

Attempt:

Let $y \geq 0$ a positive operator in $B(H)$. I need to show that
$$\text{Tr}(xy) \geq 0$$

Of course, we can write $x = a^* a, y =b^ *b$ for some operators $a,b$. And then we need to show that

$$\text{Tr}(a^* a b^*b) \geq 0$$

It seems natural to try to use the cyclicity of the trace:
$$\text{Tr}(a^*ab^*b) = \text{Tr}(ba^* ab^*) = \text{Tr}((ab^*)^*(ab^*))$$

and then we can conclude since the trace of a positive operator is positive.

However, I only know that $\text{Tr}(uv) = \text{Tr}(vu)$ when either $u$ or $v$ is trace class, so what I need for the above to work is that $a$ or $b$ is trace class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x$ is trace-class, so is $xy$. And $xy^{1/2}$. As you know that you can commute inside the trace if one of the two operators is trace-class,
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(xy)=\operatorname{Tr}(xy^{1/2}y^{1/2})=\operatorname{Tr}(y^{1/2}xy^{1/2})\geq0,
$$
as this last operator is trace-class and positive.

Comment: I have rewritten the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now. :)